# working as a physiotherapist in france for non EU residents

Tags: france, non-residents

I'm an Israeli interested in working as a physio in france. I'm looking for details regarding the procedure of reciv

Comment: *procedure of reciv*? It looks like your post is cut off. Your question is also very broad. What have you found so far and what is unclear about that?

Comment: you're right. missed that. I was wondering what is the procedure of getting a license in France? What will be required from me?

Comment: "for non-EU residents" confuses me.  Do you mean that the physiotherapy patients would reside outside the EU or that the physiotherapist resides outside the EU?  Since neither of those makes much sense without a lot of commuting, are you in fact asking about the process of becoming authorized to work as a physiotherapist in France for someone who is not an EU *citizen?*  If so, should we assume that the person is a physiotherapist with a license in some other jurisdiction?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the relevant Association for France https://www.wcpt.org/countries? There is also a process to obtain a European Professional Card but my understanding is that it requires your home country to be an EU member https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/professional-qualifications/european-professional-card/index_en.htm